# virtual box linux guest dead after host MacOS autoupdate while guest was running

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I know that I should have powered off the guest, but I was away from the computer when a forced update occured to MacOS host.

At first the manager said the virtual machine was still running when it was not.

I then right clicked to save it, then tried to go back to it and it didn't work

I then discarded the saved sate and tried to restart and got the same error

> The virtual machine 'xxxxxxxxx' has terminated unexpectedly during startup because of signal 6.
>
> Result Code: 
>   NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
>   Component: 
>   MachineWrap
>   Interface: 
>   IMachine {5047460a-265d-4538-b23e-ddba5fb84976}

Any suggestions would be very gratefully received,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I don't know why, but this was fixed by finishing updates on the host Mac OS and rebooting....

Comment: I can't accept this answer for two days - so maybe I should just delete the question - any thoughts?

Comment: Just wait a couple of days and accept :)

Comment: @bertieb - ok will do :-)